# Can't figure out why my for loop is only finding the first element in the list

Tags: python

I am looking to see if someone can help me figure out why my for loop is only finding the first element. It's not finding any of the OR elements. I am newer to Python so I am sure it's something simple.

```
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_month = yesterday.strftime('%m')
yesterday_day = yesterday.strftime('%d')
yesterday_year = yesterday.strftime('%Y')
two_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=2)
two_days_ago_month = yesterday.strftime('%m')
two_days_ago_day = yesterday.strftime('%d')
two_days_ago_year = yesterday.strftime('%Y')
three_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=3)
three_days_ago_month = yesterday.strftime('%m')
three_days_ago_day = yesterday.strftime('%d')
three_days_ago_year = yesterday.strftime('%Y')

    if event == '-WEEKEND UPDATE-':
        filemap = r'C:\Users\__\Desktop\Data Files\Reporting'
        final_sheet = pd.DataFrame()
        os.chdir(filemap)

        for file in os.listdir(filemap):
            if file.startswith(
                    fr'DetailReport_{yesterday_month}{yesterday_day}')\
                or file.startswith(
                    fr'DetailReport_{two_days_ago_month}{two_days_ago_day}')\
                or file.startswith(
                    fr'DetailReport_{three_days_ago_month}{three_days_ago_day}'):
                if file.endswith(f'{three_days_ago_year}.txt'):
                    df1 = pd.read_csv(file, sep='|', encoding='UTF-8', on_bad_lines='warn', quotechar='"', quoting=3)
                    final_sheet = pd.concat([df1, final_sheet], ignore_index=True)
        dropcolumns = ['Address', 'First Name', 'Last Name']

        final_sheet = final_sheet.drop(columns=dropcolumns)
```

Comment: Please add all other details passed in f-strings

Comment: All of your `two_days_ago_X` and `three_days_ago_X` variables are being based on `yesterday`, rather than the indicated time period.  Therefore they would only match if `yesterday` already matched.

Comment: Print every file returned from os.listdir() then consider your comparison logic to determine why certain files are (apparently) being ignored. Maybe there is only one file that complies with the conditions

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details, including sample data and log - output of ```os.listdir(filemap)``` and ```today``` in this case. Maybe you have solved the problem while preparing that [mre].